# Delete a row based on the first value of the group

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
  group health   result
1     a      H    7
2     a      H    8
3     a      N    9
4     b      H    10
5     b      H    5
6     b      H    4
7     c      H    3
8     c      H    2
9     c      N    1
```

I would like to keep the data grouped and only delete the entire group if the first result in each group is less than 7.

The outcome would look like this:

```
  group health   result
1     a      H    7
2     a      H    8
3     a      N    9
4     b      H    10
5     b      H    5
6     b      H    4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(result[1] >=7 ) .SD, group]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   filter(first(result) >=7)
#   group health result
#  <chr>  <chr>  <int>
#1     a      H      7
#2     a      H      8
#3     a      N      9
#4     b      H     10
#5     b      H      5
#6     b      H      4
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
df1[with(df1, as.logical(ave(result, group, FUN = function(x) x[1] >=7))),]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or using `aggregate`:

```
a <- aggregate(df$result ~ df$group,df,head,1) # take the first row of each group
df[df$group %in% a[a[,2] >= 7,][,1],]

  # group health result
# 1     a      H      7
# 2     a      H      8
# 3     a      N      9
# 4     b      H     10
# 5     b      H      5
# 6     b      H      4
```